# Combine date time start and end in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

I have data start time and end time. below is an example :

| Start Time | End Time | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-30 06:25:00 | 2021-01-31 00:00:00 | Loading |
| 2021-01-31 07:00:00 | 2021-02-01 08:00:00 | Trouble |
| 2021-01-31 00:00:00 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | Loading |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 2021-02-02 05:15:00 | Loading |

the start time and end time are adjusted according to each record, Expected output is below:

| Start Time | End Time | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-30 06:25:00 | 2021-01-31 07:00:00 | Loading |
| 2021-01-31 07:00:00 | 2021-01-31 08:00:00 | Trouble |
| 2021-01-31 08:00:00 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | Loading |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 2021-02-02 05:15:00 | Loading |

Your answer is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please explain the logic.  And provide a database tag.

Comment: okay brother, I have added the description :), please help me

Comment: Do you only have to do this for a single time series of data that is already overlapped/abutting, or are there additional columns and/or gaps to take account of?

Comment: Yes brother, single time series of data that is already abutting.

Comment: How do you know when to change the start time and when to change the end time?  It is not obvious.

Comment: bro, what I need is to change the endtime date value to the start time row :)